# Using connman, how can I set resolv.conf options when connman keeps overring the file?

Tags: networking

I want to set the `single-request` option in `resolv.conf` but `connman` keeps overriding the file. I see some things can be set in `/var/lib/connman/*/settings`, but seemingly not this.

Comment: Have you tried adding this option to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and running `resolvconf -u`?

Comment: Unfortunately as I am using a weird and wacky embedded variant of Linux (Angstrom) I don't have resolvconf available. Thanks for the input though, appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there's a [patch](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network.connman/15445) for connman that prevents it from changing resolv.conf, but you'll have to recompile it from source and use it on your own risk.

There's another option - to protect your /etc/resolv.conf file using the chattr command:

`chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. I concluded that this was my only real solution. Unfortunately I didn't like it, so I cheated by separately modifying resolv.conf via a service in the end (yeah, miserable hack I agree)